# Render view in ajax request error

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have a partial `(partial/article.blade.php)` .. i make ajax request to this controller action .. so i want to return this partial in response to this ajax request .. then append the result by javascript...

i'm using this code in my controller action :

```
return View::make('partial.article')
        ->with('articles',$articles);
```

In response i got this result :

```
<div class="text-center">

</div>
```

partial.article :

```
@foreach ($articles as $article)
    @include('partial.articleBlock')                    
@endforeach
<div class="text-center">
    {{ $articles->links() }}
</div>
```

What's the wrong with my code please ?
Thank you .

Comment: Your `article.blade.php` code?

Comment: I added the code my friend .

Comment: `$articles->links()` might be empty!

Comment: just for the pagination ..

Comment: I'm assuming that `$articles` is either an array or a collection. If so, is `$articles` empty?

Comment: Did you tried to dump the articles object?

Comment: $articles = DB::table('articles')->paginate(10) .. Yes i was dump articles it contains an array of articles object

Comment: Try add a static span inside the `foreach` to make sure the problem is not the `article` object.

Comment: I added it .. the problem is in the foreach loop !

Comment: Also share the code of `@include('partial.articleBlock')` this block

Comment: The ajax code? Perhaps shading some light... Are you trying to poll the server for new articles, so that they are rendered on the `blade view` instead of having the user refresh the page?

Comment: You are not passing any data to `@include('partial.articleBlock')` and you may have `if` condition which checks for particular variable which u never passed.

Answer (score 0):

can you dump and see whether articles variable is not empty before being passed to view, 
to return a view in ajax request you can try in the following way,

```
return View::make('partial.article')
    ->with('articles',$articles)->render();
```

Comment: No need to call the render method explicitly, Laravel will do that for you when the response object is created.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I think you need something like:

```
<div class="text-center">
  @foreach ($articles as $article)
      {{ $article->links() }}                
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Above one is just example. Here, my question is `@include('partial.articleBlock')`. What is it? I'll update this answer based on question update.